# login authentication with HttpClient returns status 463

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to connect to an API that has given me the log in example of:

```
 POST /api/login  
 Host: nephele.qtestnet.com  
 Cache-Control: no-cache  
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
 j_username= maxmccloud%40qasymphony.com&j_password=p@ssw0rd
```

I tried to implement this as:

```
class QTestDriver
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    public QTestDriver()
    {
        http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ahpra.testnet.com");
    }

    public async void Login()
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/login");
        request.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
        request.Content = new StringContent("j_username=scott&j_password=xxxx", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        HttpResponseMessage resp = await http.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

However the response I get is

```
"StatusCode: 463, ReasonPhrase: 'Unknown', Version: 1.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  X-Cache: MISS from webtitan\r\n  Proxy-Connection: close\r\n  Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 05:04:32 GMT\r\n  ETag: \"5501c94b-19c4\"\r\n  Server: nginx/1.7.9\r\n  Via: 1.0 webtitan (squid/3.0.STABLE26)\r\n  Content-Length: 6596\r\n  Content-Type: text/html\r\n}"    string
```

I have googled this but can't find anything useful about Status 463.

Comment: FYI, `HttpClient` is part of .NET, not part of C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a very odd response, and I stongly suspect the problem is on the API provider's end. When you see a status code that's not listed on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), which goes so far as to include 418 (I'm a teapot), it's a safe bet something's wrong on their end.

I'm not spotting anything wrong with your code, but to leave less room for error I'd consider using [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent) instead of StringContent. You might even consider using my [Flurl.Http](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl) library, which would reduce the whole call to something like this:

```
var resp = await "http://ahpra.testnet.com/api/login"
    .WithHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new {
        j_username = "scott",
        j_password = "xxxx"
    });
```